# Bootstrap 2.3 Responsive Navbar align-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Learning Bootstrap (and frontend-stuff in general) recently and am stuck at one particular problem. I have a navbar that scales across the whole pagewidth with a logo aligning to the left and then a followup of 5 items in an unordererd list, floating to the right. Works great as long as the responsiveness doesn't kick in. The general behavior showing when entering a certain min/max width - ordering the list-items underneath each other - is great, however, the right floating is lost somewhere down the road then. While skimming through the bootstrap-responsive.css I have trouble spotting the line responsible for this behavior. 
Does anybody have any idea where I should start looking?

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="horizontal-ad"></a>
        <ul class="nav" style="float: right;">
            <li><img src="img/ad/adhorizontal.jpg" alt="horizontal-ad"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ad/adhorizontal.jpg" alt="horizontal-ad"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ad/adhorizontal.jpg" alt="horizontal-ad"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ad/adhorizontal.jpg" alt="horizontal-ad"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ad/adhorizontal.jpg" alt="horizontal-ad"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Besides the inline-styling of the unordered list, the only rule I override is .navbar-inner from the main bootstrap.css to adjust the coloring.

Regards!

::edit: I just realized that this has nothing to do with the bootstrap-responsive.css, since I removed it but the behavior remains the same. However, the problem still exists. ::

Comment: Please can you make a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Have you tried using: `position:absolute; right: 0`

Comment: Hey there. 
Here's the fiddled setup. Haven't uploaded the images yet, behavior-wise, this shouldn't make a difference. http://jsfiddle.net/b9cgn/

I have tried your suggestion. To clearify, the UL and its elements are supposed to stay at the right side, all the time. Ordering them underneath each other, when there's not enough space, is welcome, perfect. But them moving to the left is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<ul class="nav" id="nav_ul">
```

CSS

```
#nav_ul{
float:right!important;
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought aswell. Unluckily, !important didn't solve my issue. Should have mentioned that upfront, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try Boostrap helper class pull-right:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
```

or try to display in block:

```
 <ul style="display:block" class="nav pull-right">
```

Comment: It sticks to the right but only if I remove the nav-class from the UL. This way I also lose the horizontal alignment of the list elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner clearfix">
        <a class="brand pull-left" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="horizontal-ad"></a>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><img src="img/ad/adhorizontal.jpg" alt="horizontal-ad"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ad/adhorizontal.jpg" alt="horizontal-ad"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ad/adhorizontal.jpg" alt="horizontal-ad"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ad/adhorizontal.jpg" alt="horizontal-ad"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ad/adhorizontal.jpg" alt="horizontal-ad"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
float: right!important;
clear: right;
text-align: right;
```

Also to kepp it on the same line though if the screen gets too small it will disappear so won't work well on mobile devices use this line of css:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hive7/b9cgn/4

Comment: @http://jsfiddle.net/hive7/b9cgn/4 - when minimizing, the ul-elements still move to the left underneath the logo.

Comment: Hate to say it but that's not what I try to achive, either. I think I have to go about this another, adding two divs, I presume. I'll get back to you to let you know what happend. But many thanks for trying so hard.
Best regards!